# OpenGL GL_R8 generates a 0x501, GL_RGB8 does not

Tags: opengl, texturing

This seems to be a rather straightforward problem (or at least as close as you can get). When I pass GL_RGB8, GL_RGBA8, or most any multiple-channel internal format, the below line produces no error.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, fontImgSize, fontImgSize, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

However, when I pass GL_R8 or any 8-bit one-channel variant, glGetError returns 0x501 (Invalid Value).

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, fontImgSize, fontImgSize, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

Any idea what's going on here? The computer I'm presently using is rather outdated and low-power, but if that were the problem I doubt RGB8 or RGBA8 would work.

For those curious, fontImgSize == 2048, the maximum texture size on my computer.

Edit: It appears GL_RG8 and 2-channel/16-bit formats also produce a 0x501

Comment: Looks like a driver issue, you are saying yourselves that your laptop is outdated, have you installed the latest drivers?

Comment: Well, outdated hardware-wise. I update it weekly, but even so there appears to be another driver update (intel integrated graphics). I'll install it and edit my post to reflect the results.

Comment: Intel-graphics aren't known for their OpenGL compability ;)

Comment: As I feared, updating changed nothing. It seems as if my video "card" only supports 32-bit data, but OpenGL refuses to pad anything under 24 bits.

Comment: What `GL_VERSION` does your implementation report?

Comment: 1.4, by some black magic. Double-checked the code involved twice, to make sure I wasn't swapping minor and major values.

Comment: @Precursor Do you have any further question regarding the existing answers or have you solved the problem yourself already?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only true solution was to switch computers. While many games might be able to get along without shaders and the like, they are absolutely essential for my project. However, I was able to solve the initial problem by using an older internal format, as you suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 3- and 4-component internal formats (like `GL_RGB8` and `GL_RGBA8`) have been a core feature of OpenGL since a very long time (ever?), but the 1- and 2-component internal formats (like `GL_R8` and `GL_RG8`) are a pretty new feature, requiring rather new hardware and a corresponding driver (at least OpenGL 3, I think, not so new anymore, but if you say your labtop is outdated, then probably too new).

There are older (now deprecated) 1/2-component internal formats like `GL_LUMINANCE`, `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` and `GL_INTENSITY` (and their respective sized versions), which should be supported on any older implementation. But note that those have slightly different semantics and filtering/copying behaviour compared to the newer plain color formats. But maybe they are sufficient for your use-case.

Also note that as  external formats (the format of the CPU pixel data used for reading/writing the texture data) the format `GL_RED` (and maybe also `GL_RG`?) should always be available (with the respective semantics), but that is totally unrelated to the internal texture data.

Answer (score 1):

`GL_R8` is a pretty new (well, if you consider post-GL 2.1 to be "new") format.

Try `GL_LUMINANCE8` instead.

Comment: Though `GL_LUMINANCE8` isn't really the same as `GL_R8`.